# JSF Temperature calculator

Tags: java, jsf, temperature

I am trying to create a temperature conversion program in JSF. It has got one textbox and two radio buttons to select between CEL to FRA and FRA to CEL and a submit button. I am problem getting the value of the radio buttons.  I have pasted the code as under:

Index.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Convert Temperature</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body> 
        <h1>Convert Temperature </h1>
        <f:view>
            <h:form id="tempForm">
                <h:outputText value="Enter Temperature:"/>
                <h:inputText value="#{tempconvert.temperature}" />

                <h:selectOneRadio id ="radio" value="{tempconvert.radChoice}"  layout="LINE_DIRECTION">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="radOne" itemLabel="CEL to FAR" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue ="radTwo" itemLabel="FAR to CEL" />
                </h:selectOneRadio>
                <h:commandButton action="#{tempconvert.ConvertTemp}" value="Convert" />
            </h:form>
            <br />
            <h:outputLabel value="#{tempconvert.resultlabel}" />
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

TemperatureConvertBean

```
package TemperatureConvert;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import java.util.*;

@ManagedBean(name = "tempconvert")
@RequestScoped
public class TemperatureConvertBean {
    private double temperature;
    private String resultlabel;
    private String radChoice = "radOne";

    /** Creates a new instance of TemperatureConvertBean */
    public TemperatureConvertBean() {

    }

    /**
     * @return the temperature
     */
    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    /**
     * @param temperature the temperature to set
     */
    public void setTemperature(double temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    /**
     * @return the resultlabel
     */
    public String getResultlabel() {
        return resultlabel;
    }

    /**
     * @param resultlabel the resultlabel to set
     */
    public void setResultlabel(String resultlabel) {
        this.resultlabel = resultlabel;
    }

    /**
     * @return the radChoice
     */
    public String getRadChoice() {
        return radChoice;
    }

    /**
     * @param radChoice the radChoice to set
     */
    public void setRadChoice(String radChoice) {
        this.radChoice = radChoice;
    }

    public String ConvertTemp() {

        if (this.getRadChoice().equals("radOne"))
        {

            this.resultlabel = "Radio one selected";
        }
        else
        {
            this.resultlabel = "Radio two selected";

        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Clarify your problem, please. It is hard to understand what problem do you have.

Comment: I don't see any wrong in your code.I think your bean is `@RequestScoped`, this may be a reason.Make it `@SessionScoped` any give a try!
Best of luck!

Comment: Even if it worked (I don't think so), it wouldn't have been a solution, but a workaround. You're basically abusing the session scoped here.

Comment: I know this.But according to this this code snippet, this should work

Comment: I changed it to RequestScoped still it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you :|

Your code (**I COPIED**)

```
<h:selectOneRadio id ="radio" value="{tempconvert.radChoice}"  layout="LINE_DIRECTION">
```

Your code (Editted)

```
<h:selectOneRadio id ="radio" value="#{tempconvert.radChoice}"  layout="LINE_DIRECTION">
```

P/s: It's display: "Radio two selected" when i choose the 2nd button.

Comment: just a single "#" character... next time check your syntax before posting question